# Jackson read value as Intetger

Tags: jackson

I am having Json  like this,I wanna get/read "responseCode" using Jackson,How to do this?

```
{
"successful":false,
"responseMessage":"direct address error: direct address is taken",
"responseCode":4610
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways. One is to define matching Java class with just that one field:

```
// either mark to ignore anything else; or specify field/setter for every property, both work
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Response {
   public int responseCode;
}

Response resp = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Response.class);
int responseCode = resp.responseCode;
```

or, using Tree Model

```
JsonNode root = new ObjectMapper().readTree(json);
int responseCode = root.path("responseCode)".asIntValue();
```